# Call JavaScript function inside an object

Tags: javascript

I am going through some JavaScript basics. Following is my code and question:

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
<script>
function test(){
    const printer = {
        on : true,
        mode : "black and white",
        print : printMe(" Name"),
        printAgain : function () {
            alert("Hi there!");
        }
    }
}

function printMe(name){
    alert ("Print me"+ name);
}
</script>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Test" onclick="test()"></button>
</body>
</html>
```

I can call printAgain with the below line:

```
printer.printAgain();
```

But I don't need to explicitly call printMe() method. I understand that its because I am calling it in *printer.print*.

Is there a way to reference a javascript function inside an object and then invoke it explicitly? For example: I want the `printMe()` to be called when I write `printer.print()` in my code.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L8akx36j/

Comment: `print : printMe(" Name"),` here you are invoking the `printMe()` function then assigning returned value to the `print` property of `printer` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `printer.print` to a reference to `printMe`:

```js
function test(){
    const printer = {
        on : true,
        mode : "black and white",
        print : printMe,
        printAgain : function () {
            alert("Hi there!");
        }
    }
    printer.print(" Name");
}

function printMe(name){
    alert ("Print me"+ name);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Test" onclick="test()"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can reference a function simply by its name. Only when add parenthesis it gets called. I assume this is what you want:

```
const printer = {
    on : true,
    mode : "black and white",
    print : printMe,
    printAgain : function () {
        alert("Hi there!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the function has arguments?

Comment: Nevermind. I think I can just pass the arguments when I call.

Comment: If you do want arguments, then wrap the function in another function

Comment: Or I can just pass the arguments when I call the function as @Majed Badawi posted above.

Comment: @PKJ That's the same thing as I suggested here.